# CDK 2.x: How to grant accounts within an AWS Organization pull access on an AWS ECR repository?

Tags: aws-cdk, amazon-ecr, aws-organizations

I am looking for example code describing how to grant pull access to an ECR repository across accounts in various sub-units of a AWS Organization hierarchy.  Ideally, I would like to allowlist an organization unit.  If necessary, I could allowlist accounts individually.

So far, I have started with the following Typescript deployed to the accounting holding the ECR repository:

```js
const ecr_access_user = new iam.User(
      this,
      "build-docker-access" + stageSuffix,
      {
        userName: "build-docker-access" + stageSuffix,
      }
    );
repository.grantPull(ecr_access_user)
```

Now, how do I set up a policy that will grant access within an AWS Organization unit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a [*resource policy*](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/repository-policies.html) for the repository granting permissions to the OUs you want through [OU matching condition keys](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/iam-share-aws-resources-groups-aws-accounts-aws-organizations/).

```js
repository.addToResourcePolicy(
  new iam.PolicyStatement({
    principals: [new iam.AnyPrincipal()], // or specify specific accounts
    actions: ["ecr:*"], // modify as needed
    conditions: {
      "ForAnyValue:StringLike": {
        "aws:PrincipalOrgPaths": ["o-my-organization/*/ou-abc/*"], // modify as needed
      },
    },
  })
);
```

Whatever principal wants to pull from the repo will also need the `ecr:GetAuthorizationToken` permission granted separately (since this permission does not belong to any specific resource).